# How to use email domain names to update a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, compare

I have two tables in the same SQL Server database. Table1 is a table that contains 'Email' and 'CompanyName' and is being used as a reference table. Table2 has the same columns but some of the CompanyName fields are missing.

I would like to use the domain names (everything after the @) from the 'Email' column in Table1 in conjunction with its respective 'CompanyName' to then populate the missing 'CompanyName' in Table2 if the Email domain name from Table1 matches an Email domain name in Table2.

So for example, let's say I have an entry in Table1 where the Email = 'bob@gsk.com', 'fred@jhmi.edu' and its respective CompanyName = 'glaxosmithkline', 'Johns Hopkins'.

Then in Table2 I have an Email = 'tiffany@gsk.com', 'john@jhmi.edu' and CompanyName is blank

I'd like to use the @gsk.com and @jhmi.edu part to match and then fill in 'glaxosmithkline' and 'Johns Hopkins' into the Table2 CompanyName column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is use a CTE to get the domains and then update your table.

```
with cteDomain as(
select distinct
    CompanyName, 
    right(Email,len(Email) - CHARINDEX('@',Email,0)) as Domain --this is making assumptions as you posted
from Table1)

update Table2
set t2.CompanyName = d.CompanyName
from Table2 t2
inner join cteDomain d on right(t2.Email,len(t2.Email) - CHARINDEX('@',t2.Email,0)) = d.Domain
where ISNULL(t2.CompanyName,'') = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a third table with the company name and domain and rather use that as a reference in both as you will have a unique entry per company

Then using some string manipulation I you can get everything after charindex('@',Email) and before charindex('.',Email) to compare to that new tables domain field.